# How to generate SINGLE source map file for all chunks

Tags: webpack, source-maps

is there any way to generate a single sourcemap file for all chunks using webpack.
Here is my webpack config:

```
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        terserOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: false
          }
        }
      })
```

and I'm using SourceMapDevToolPlugin:

```
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: '../sourcemaps/[file].map',
      exclude: /react|vendors|moment|lodash*.*/
    })
```

It will generate source map file for each chunks.
I tried to config filename to something static like `../sourcemaps/source.js.map` but it didn't work as expected. How can I generate a single source map file that can be used for all chunks?

Thanks